# MATLAB solve() can't solve trigonometric matrix for specific values

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math, euler-angles

I'm experiencing something very strange in MATLAB which I can't figure out.

I have 2 sets of coordinates of a body for which I want to find the Euler angles. I set up the rotation matrix `R` and the symbolic Cardan angles matrix `R_cardan` to solve for the angles. For the first set I can simply do `solve(R==R_cardan)` but when I use the second set it doesn't work. The solution returned is empty.

What could be causing this? Here is test code.

```
clc;clear;close all;

%% For some reason R2 does not want to give a solution
% Find rotation matrix to transform from origin to local reference frame
ex = [ 0.768  0.024 0.640].';
ey = [-0.424  0.768 0.480].';
ez = [-0.480 -0.640 0.600].';

ex2 = [ 0.612372  0.353553 -0.707107].';
ey2 = [0.280330  0.739199 0.612372].';
ez2 = [0.739199 -0.573223 0.353553].';

R = eye(3)*[ex ey ez]
R2 = eye(3)*[ex2 ey2 ez2]
% Symbolic variables
syms beta alpha gamma

% Set up rotatin matrices
R_alpha = [cos(alpha) -sin(alpha) 0; sin(alpha) cos(alpha) 0; 0 0 1]
R_beta = [cos(beta) 0 sin(beta); 0 1 0; -sin(beta) 0 cos(beta)]
R_gamma  = [1 0 0; 0 cos(gamma) -sin(gamma); 0 sin(gamma) cos(gamma)]

% Find symbolic rotation matrix
R_cardan = R_alpha*R_beta*R_gamma

[alpha, beta, gamma] = find_angles(R,R_cardan)
[alpha, beta, gamma] = find_angles(R2,R_cardan) %fails because solution is empty

function [alpha, beta, gamma] = find_angles(R,R_cardan)

% Solve for the angles
sol = solve(R == R_cardan);
alpha = double(sol.alpha(1));
beta = double(sol.beta(1));
gamma = double(sol.gamma(1));

end
```

My current solution is to just manually calculate the angles which is fine, but I'm interested in what is wrong with my method above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem will be that you solve for an *exact* match `R == R_cardan`. As you are working with a finite precision, this is dangerous and it can be that there is no solution, as it happens for `R2`. Your goal is to find a solution which makes the difference `R - R_cardan` very small - ideally zero.

I would do the following instead: Create a loss function

[image: Loss]

and minimize this function. The ideal solution at `R = R_cardan` would lead to a loss of zero, but even if this is numerically not possible, you would get a solution which is as close to the optimal solution as possible (in terms of Euclidean distance).

In MATLAB, this is a bit complicated, but well described in the [help pages](https://ch.mathworks.com/help/optim/examples/using-symbolic-mathematics-with-optimization-toolbox-solvers.html).

1. Define the loss function in terms of `R` and `R_cardan`, and put all unknowns into a vector `x`:

   ```
   f = sum(sum((R - R_cardan).^2));
   x = [alpha; beta; gamma];
   ```
2. Analytically calculate the gradient and Hessian of the loss function:

   ```
   gradf = jacobian(f, x).'; % column gradf
   hessf = jacobian(gradf, x);
   ```
3. Convert these functions from symbolic functions to MATLAB function handles:

   ```
   fh = matlabFunction(f, gradf, hessf, 'vars', {x});
   ```
4. Set up the optimizer to use the gradient and Hessian:

   ```
   options = optimoptions('fminunc', 'SpecifyObjectiveGradient', true, ... 
                                     'HessianFcn', 'objective', ...
                                     'Algorithm', 'trust-region')
   ```
5. Minimize!

   ```
   solution = fminunc(fh, [0;0;0], options);
   alpha_hat = solution(1);
   beta_hat = solution(2);
   gamma_hat = solution(3);
   ```

For the first example `R`, this gives the exact same solution as with `solve`.
For the second example `R2`, the reconstructed matrix `R2_hat` (obtained by plugging the estimated values into `R_cardan`) is *almost* the same as `R2`, but has some differences in the least significant digits:

```
R2 =
    0.6124    0.2803    0.7392
    0.3536    0.7392   -0.5732
   -0.7071    0.6124    0.3536

R2_hat =
    0.6125    0.2805    0.7390
    0.3533    0.7392   -0.5734
   -0.7071    0.6123    0.3537
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This is a very nice but complicated solution. It is definitely worth while, though, to know this particular way of solving the problem.